# Creating directory structure from custom ribbon action

Tags: development, 2013, javascript, client-object-model, apps-development

Environment: 2013, VS2012

I'm trying to develop a custom ribbon button for a document library that creates a folder (ie: a new project) and populates it with a hierarchy of sub-folders. I have some basic c# code that makes the directory structure on the file system and can then dump it into the library, but am unsure of how to call it using the jscript that seems to be the standard for these custom actions. For example, [this](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html) article describes how to get the button, but I don't know how to bridge that with my c# app. I'm not a javascript developer by any stretch of the imagination, but I can follow instructions pretty well if anyone can point me to an article or can describe the process here.

Of course, alternatives are acceptable. I've seen people saying you can't execute server-side code from a ribbon button, so if there's a different way of creating the folder structure, I'm all ears (figuratively).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SP2013 or VS2012 yet, but if I were trying to do something in SharePoint that I would normally do with C# and the server object model (server side code), and had to use Javascript, I'd look for ways to do it using the client object model.

[JavaScript API reference for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193034.aspx)